# How to check character count for Google Translation API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using the following code to translate using the google translation API

```
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
translate_client = translate.Client(credentials=credentials)

# if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
#     text = text.decode('utf-8')

# Text can also be a sequence of strings, in which case this method
# will return a sequence of results for each text.
result = translate_client.translate(
    text, target_language='en')

print(u'Text: {}'.format(result['input']))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(result['translatedText']))
print(u'Detected source language: {}'.format(
    result['detectedSourceLanguage']))
```

How can I keep track as to how many characters a remaining or have been used till now? I have 1 million free characters.

Answer (score 3):

Even I do not think there is a direct way of requesting such information (apart from the console), there is a way of creating alerting policies internally.

You can set an alerting policy that is triggered for a certain number of requested bytes and apply 1 char = 8 bit = 1 byte.

In order to do that, you should go Monitoring -> Alerting -> Create New Policy ->

```
  ·Resource type: Consumed API
  ·Metric: Request sizes 
  ·Filter -> Service = translate.googleapis.com
```

and configure as much triggers as you like.
I hope this finds well!

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the value in a file? Every time you translate `n` characters,

1. read the `count` from file
2. increment `count` by `n`
3. write `count` back to the file

Comment: Well, that's a workaround I have implemented. I want it from the official source.

Comment: Also, how do I count Chinese characters?

Comment: @Shawn the same way we are storing the test and count in our log database before sending to google api , as per our log the count is 18k+ but google billing shows 48k+ so we are looking what are the other request been sent to google , did you got any solution on it

Comment: @Thom AFAIK when you translate something both the input and output chars are taken into account. Ex. If 10,000 chars are sent for translation and the resulting text is 11,000 chars, the total would be 21,000 chars.