# Where to see how many characters are left of the free tier of the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

Is there any place in the console to show how many characters are still available from the 1 million free tier characters of the Google Cloud TTS API?

Comment: I guess the consumed numbers of characters by TTS API will only show in your billing reports once you exceeded free tier limits, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60562334/9928809) solution using alert policies that might be useful. Does it sound reasonable for you?